# How to pause the .AHK script at the End Of the Program in Auto Hot Key

Tags: .net, autohotkey

I Need some help from you guys, could any one help me out ??

I need to pause my .AHK Script at the End of the Program.

Here is my Code:

```
#SingleInstance force
Run, C:\Pangaea\Software\SVN\TortoiseSVN-1.8.8.25755-x64-svn-1.8.10.msi
#Persistent
SetTimer, Check, 1000  

Check:
IfWinActive, ahk_class MsiDialogCloseClass
ControlClick, &Next >,ahk_class MsiDialogCloseClass

IfWinActive, ahk_class MsiDialogCloseClass
ControlClick, Remove Installation,ahk_class MsiDialogCloseClass

IfWinActive, ahk_class MsiDialogCloseClass
ControlClick,&Remove,ahk_class MsiDialogCloseClass

IfWinActive, ahk_class MsiDialogCloseClass
ControlClick,&Finish,ahk_class MsiDialogCloseClass

SetControlDelay -1

Return
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this command, it pauses the script's current thread:

https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Pause.htm

Answer (score 0):

You want the script to exit when the process is no longer open.
To check for process existence use: `Process, Exist`.

```
#SingleInstance force
Run, C:\Pangaea\Software\SVN\TortoiseSVN-1.8.8.25755-x64-svn-1.8.10.msi
#Persistent
SetTimer, Check, 1000

Check:
Process, Exist, TortoiseSVN-1.8.8.25755-x64-svn-1.8.10.msi
if !ErrorLevel
ExitApp

IfWinActive, ahk_class MsiDialogCloseClass
ControlClick, &Next >,ahk_class MsiDialogCloseClass

IfWinActive, ahk_class MsiDialogCloseClass
ControlClick, Remove Installation,ahk_class MsiDialogCloseClass

IfWinActive, ahk_class MsiDialogCloseClass
ControlClick,&Remove,ahk_class MsiDialogCloseClass

IfWinActive, ahk_class MsiDialogCloseClass
ControlClick,&Finish,ahk_class MsiDialogCloseClass

SetControlDelay -1

Return
```

Or, if you want the script to pause when the process is no longer open,
because you might launch the process again manually, later,
use `Return` instead of `ExitApp`.

```
Process, Exist, TortoiseSVN-1.8.8.25755-x64-svn-1.8.10.msi
if !ErrorLevel
Return
```